# Rails - How do I loop through arrays in a hash to display html table data (the values of the array go in one table cell for each array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have the following table

```
<table>
    <tr>   
      <% @table_header.each do |key, value| %>

       <th> <%= value %></th>

      <% end %>
    <tr>   
<% @item_id.each do |item_id| %>
    <tr>  

      <% @table_content.each do |key, content| %>
      <!-- line below is the main focus -->
       <td> <%= CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: content, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value) %></td>
       <% end %>

    <tr>   
       <% end %>
</table >
```

The table displays content from the DB. You can ignore the header, it works fine and is made form a hash. My problem is the table data.

`items` have different sets of `values` and the each set of values is given a unique key e.g. the key 'color' will grab that items color value. This setup works fine for normal hashes like the one below

```
normal_hash = {"key1"=>"color", "key2"=>"speed", "key3"=>"weight", "key4"=>"height"}
```

With the table above if you replace `@table_content` with `normal_hash` it will work fine, and display each items, color, speed etc..

But now I want to have a hash like this

```
new_hash = {"key1"=>["color", "age"], "key2"=>"speed", "key3"=>["weight", "brand"], "key4"=>"height"}
```

So I can display 2 values in one table cell instead of just one. I don't know how to loop through the array in the hash for the keys that have arrays as values while keep both values in the one table cell.

You can see how I currently do it by doing a `.find_by` call to the db and have the `key:` be assigned the value in the hash which then grabs the right item value for that table cell. I need it to run this line again for that same `td` if the hash value is an array. So the one cell can have multiple values for one item shown. How can this be done?

Hope that makes sense. If its easier I can have all hash values be arrays (but most will have one value in the array)

**update**

Basically the form above loops through normal hashes putting one value in each table cell (I made `normal_hash` as an example of a normal hash). This loop is done from these lines (replace `@table_content` with `normal_hash`.

```
<% @table_content.each do |key, content| %>
          <!-- line below is the main focus -->
           <td> <%= CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: content, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value) %></td>
           <% end %>
```

I need it to loop through hashes like `new_hash` (instead of hashes like `normal_hash` that has arrays as values in the hash. So it can have more than one value in the table cell.

Comment: I'm finding it very difficult to follow what your trying to do and what your asking. I think you should reformat your question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you make all values arrays as you mention at the end of your question. The you can just use `join` on your arrays, like so:

```
CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: content, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value).try(:join, ', ')
```

This will put a comma separated list of your values in the cell (replace ', ' with "\n" if you want the items on different lines, or whichever separator you need).

If you don't want to change the hash, you need to check if your value is an `Array`; one way to do that is: `CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: content, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value).try(:is_a?, Array)`. Then you'd use `join` if it is an array, and the value directly if not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed them all to arrays but it doesn't seem to do anything. It leaves the table cells blank when I add `.try(:join, ', ')`. Without `.try(:join, ', ')` the current setup I have shows the first value in the array

Comment: Can you try in the console? Eventually if you know that value is always present and always an array you can get rid of both the `try` methods.

Comment: Uh i'm not sure how to enter multiple line coding in the console (in this case the loop). The value will always be an array but no always present.

Comment: You can use multiple lines in the console, it's smart enough to parse that correctly and run the whole thing when you enter the final `end`. That said, you don't really need to run the loop, you can just `find_by` a key where you know there is an array as value, and see what this returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your question:
     I don't know how to loop through the array in the hash for the keys that have arrays as values while keep both values in the one table cell.

You need to create one variable to store hash array value. In example, 
to store key1 value

```
new_hash = {"key1"=>["color", "age"], "key2"=>"speed", "key3"=>["weight", "brand"], "key4"=>"height"}
key1_arr = new_hash["key1"] #this is to get key1 array
if(key1_arr.class = "Array") #see type of object
  key1_arr.each do |val_key1|
    ..your ..logic ..for array.. ..here
  end 
else
   ..your ..logic ..for ..non ..array
end
```

Comment: Ok and to save on doing this logic lets say I make them all arrays. How would I loop through the arrays values so all of them show in the one table cell. currently with the setup in my question it just shows the first value in the array.

Comment: Put this line in the loop part
`CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: content, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value)`

Comment: But this only works for the first key. the number of keys in the hash isn't a set number so I cant hard code arrays for all keys and hard code the table to have `keyx_arr.each do |val_key1| ` for each column.

Answer (score 0):

I made each value in the hash an array

`new_hash = {"key1"=>["color", "age"], "key2"=>["speed"], "key3"=>["weight", "brand"], "key4"=>["height"]}`

I then had a loop inside the `new_hash` loop to loop through the arrays inside `<td>` tags.

```
 <% new_hash.each do |key, content| %>

   <td><p> 
     <% content.each do |key_value| %>
        <%= CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: key_value, category_item_id: item_id).try(:value) %>, 
    <% end %>
   <p></td>

   <% end %>
```